# How to access provider in model class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a class which is not a widget , so it doesn't have any context. So is there any way I can access Class with ChangeNotifier within this model class.

**Model Class**

```
class MyRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
@override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {

    
    Provider.of<MyCass>(context, listen: false).restore();  // How I can do this ? as I dont have context here

    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (previousRoute is PageRoute && route is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(previousRoute);
    }
  }
}
```

**My Class**

```
class MyClass with ChangeNotifier {

  void restore() {
    .. Some logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add context filed to your class

```
final BuildContext context;
```

then add it to constructor

```
const MyRouteObserver(this.context);
```

so you can pass build context to your class from your widget class

Comment: Do not hold on to a context.  They are all different even when in the same widget.  You need the *current* context always.